# Tkinter StringVar() concatenation

Tags: python, excel, string, user-interface, tkinter

I am using Tkinter lib for Python gui, and I'd like to display text from excel sheet using a loop, and a label inside a frame, however, since StringVar has only set function, I can not insert new values, or concatenate the string

```
print('Matched Tweets')
        for i, element in enumerate(ranked_tweets):
            for j in range(1, 8):
             result.set(worksheet._get_cell((element + 1), j).value+"\n")
        #result.set("\n")
```

in which, result is stringVar and it is shown inside lable in the gui

```
Label1= ttk.Label(frame1, textvariable=result)
```

and when I ran the application, it only shows one result given that it overwrites the variable with set method each iteration.

My question is, how to list all the texts using the stringVar

Comment: first concatenate all strings and later use `set()`. Or: `StringVar` has also `get()`so you can do `result.set( result.get() + "new text")`

Answer (score 6):

StringVar has a `get()` method too:

```
new_data = worksheet._get_cell((element + 1), j).value+"\n"
result.set(result.get() + new_data)
```